# How to print value of .hasClass via console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

using the Firebug console I'm trying to test whether this code is working:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('#tab1link').click(function() {
        $('#tab2').hide();
        $('#tab2').removeClass('selected');
        $('#tab1').show();
        $('#tab1').addClass('selected');
    });

    $('#tab2link').click(function() {
        $('#tab1').hide();
        $('#tab1').removeClass('selected');
        $('#tab2').show();
        $('#tab2').addClass('selected');
    });

});
```

but this:

```
console.log($('#tab2').hasClass('selected'))
```

returns the error:

```
 TypeError: $("#tab2").hasClass is not a function { message="$("#tab2").hasClass is not a function",  more...}
```

Does anyone know why the above console command is incorrect? (Not a jQuery expert...)

Based on the link below, I think it should work...
http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you also have prototype in the page, possibly a `.noConflict()` call in there?

Comment: console.log() is called manually or is it placed somewhere in document? If it's in document, isn't it called too early, before jQuery is initialized?

Comment: yedpodtrzitko: sorry, I should have been more clear, I'm calling hasClass from the console (manually)

Comment: Nick: I haven't added a .noConflict but it's not my original code so theoretically it could be there. Is it worth digging through the code if the alert test below passes?

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the console/page because sometimes it doesn't properly assign `$` to jQuery, assuming you're using Firebug ( it keeps the native $ function which ISNT jquery ).

You can confirm this with:

```
alert( $ == jQuery )
```

If this isn't it, then make sure you aren't using multiple libraries that use `$`.

Unrelated: You can also do `$(function(){ /* code */ });` instead of binding on window load.

Comment: Your test comes back true, so $ == jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
console.log(jQuery('#tab2').hasClass('selected'))
```

It looks suspiciously like the `$` is given up but still in use, like Prototype in included in the page and [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) was called (which means `$ != jQuery` when you're running commands in the console later).

Comment: I tried that and receive the same error. Using the test above, alert ($ == jQuery), I've confirmed that the $ should respond.